# Symfony2 skeleton app with auth and users from sql

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Can anybody please provide some Symfony2 skeleton application with already working auth to admin area with users from SQL (editable via some form in the app) ideally styled with Twitter Bootstrap 2 or 3?

I am newbie in Symfony2 and wanna see some working app, because it is better to learn from working code for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the symfony2 framework as described here: [Symfony Installation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#installing-a-symfony2-distribution)

Then you can install these bundles:

- User Management system: [FOS UserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle#fosuserbundle)
- Admin panel: [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html)
- For the twitter bootstrap 2 styling (they are working on twitter bootstrap 3 support): [BrainCraftedBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle#bcbootstrapbundle)

As an extra example you could look at [sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius), it's a project with mostly these bundles (above bundles) included, so you can look at some premade code!

This will give you all the pieces for a system you asked for, only you need to modify a few thing to get it working together! Good luck!